# power steering fluid is being pushed out of the top of my resevior

Tags: honda, accord, power-steering

Power steering fluid is being pushed out of the top of my reservoir of my 98 Honda accord and I don't know what is causing it. I'm going through a bottle a week can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Has there been any recent work done to the car for the steering or steering system? Are you sure you just aren't over filling the reservoir?How are you adding fluid to the system?